# logging iisreset

Tags: iis, iis-6

Is there a log that lets you know when the web site was stopped and started in iis?

I'm looking for a way to see when the web site was stopped and started.

Does anyone know if there is a way to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to put something in your global.asax file in Application_start.

You can add something to a log file, or shoot yourself an email whenever this fires.

Comment: This will indicate that the website started.  It will not necessarily indicate the cause: it could be because the application pool was stopped and started, or because the application pool timed out or because the web.config has been modified.  Just be aware of that there are many reasons why Application_start is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Windows Event Viewer > Windows Logs > System.

Filter events with `Source` = `IIS-IISReset`.

An example event message is:

> IIS stop command received from user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. The logged data is the status code.