# How can I know if and when IIS was reset in the past?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I'm having some troubles in my production environment, I found some clues that can lead to an IIS reset, but I'm not sure.

How and where can I find if there was an IIS reset **in the past**?

Edit:

Regarding the future resets the Kevin's solutions is ok and I have successfully used it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Global.asax file on your ASP .Net application.  Then you can hook into the application start and stop events with the following methods:

```
public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // log iis started 
}

public void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // log iis stopped
}
```

All you have to do is declare these methods in your global.asax file, ASP .Net will automatically call them when your application is started/stopped.  You can then do any logging code you need inside these methods.

Comment: Your solution seems to be the [popular consensus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143129/logging-iisreset)

Comment: This is a good solution for the future issues, but unfortunately it can't help to discover past issues.

Comment: Furthermore, you wrote 2 times Application_Start. Did you mean Application_End on second time?